# How to print all content of array

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, tostring

If I have a class like this

```
public class Car
{
    private string number;
    private string brand;
    private string model;
    private double kilometers;


    public Car(string n,string b,string m,double km)
    {
        number = n;
        brand = b;
        model = m;
        kilometers = km;
    }
}
```

And arrays like this

```
Car[] car;
car = new Car[5];
car[0] = new Car("01", "Audi", "R8", 2593);
car[1] = new Car("02", "Jaguar", "F-Type", 12432);
car[2] = new Car("03", "Porsche", "Cayman", 87643);
car[3] = new Car("04", "Mclaren", "675 LT", 34265);
car[4] = new Car("05", "Ferrari", "458 Italia", 2145);
```

Assume that `i` is position of array.
How do I show of all my content in `car[i]` in a single line.

Comment: Is your question related to arrays or just how to print out an object?

Comment: My question is related to array and I want to print out a object in my arrays

Comment: Well if you can print one object you can also print many objects by repeating the same for one many times.

Comment: What should I do if i only need to print just content of array that I have input the position of array

Comment: Do you want to print it for debugging purposes in watch or as a output of your application?

Answer (score 10):

You can override `ToString` for `Car` class

```
public class Car
{
    .....
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{{ Number = \"{0}\", Brand= \"{1}\", Model = \"{2}\", Kilometers = \"{3}\" }}",
                              this.number, this.brand, this.model, this.kilometers);

// if using C# 6.0 you can use string interpolation instead.
// return $"{{ Number = \"{this.number}\", Brand= \"{this.brand}\", Model = \"{this.model}\", Kilometers = \"{this.kilometers}\" }}";

    }
}
```

and then simply print them all in `Console`

```
foreach (var c in car)
{
    Console.WriteLine(c);

    // Console.WriteLine(Object) will call the ToString method of input Object to produce its string representation, and the resulting string is written to the standard output stream.
}
```

Or print just one of them like `Console.WriteLine(car[i]);`

Comment: what is "i" in Console.WriteLine(car[i]);?

Comment: `Console.WriteLine` will call `ToString` of input parameters automatically @Neel

Comment: I have define my class like this'public Car(string n,string b,string m,double km)
        {
            number = n;
            brand = b;
            model = m;
            kilometers = km;
        }'

Comment: I gave you a hint, you can change the text in format string and fields in your class to meet the requirements.